# Unable to link CSS file

Tags: plugin-development, css, redirect

I use this to link to my CSS file:

```
$css_file = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'MapStyle.css';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="', $css_file, '" >';
```

Which (correctly) resolves as (echo $css_file):

```
/var/www/mysite/wp-content/plugins/TheMapPlugin/MapStyle.css
```

But the css file is never loaded, because the browser is looking for the file:

```
http://www.example.com/var/www/mysite/wp-content/plugins/TheMapPlugin/MapStyle.css
```

What am I overlooking here? All help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to register the style and css using wp_register_script() and wp_register_style() functions

```
 //registering css
 wp_register_style ( 'mysample', plugins_url ( 'css/MapStyle.css', __FILE__ ) );
 wp_register_script ( 'mysample', plugins_url ( 'js/MapStyle.js', __FILE__ ) );
```

After this you can call the wp_enqueue_style() functions for loading the  css in required page

```
wp_enqueue_style('mysample');
wp_enqueue_script('mysample');
```

Comment: Great :-) That worked like a charm! Just a question: are there similar methods for JS and images?

Comment: For images you can use `plugins_url ( 'img/image.png', __FILE__ )`